# Error al adaptar código de matlab a python: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python

tengo que adaptar un texto de matlab a python y me esta costando
el codigo es el siguiente en matlab:

```
clear all
%Stress calculation using Logiet et al. equations and Holms case to
%validate FEM models of tubes

%Holms case properties
E=120.66e9; %Young modulus, E=120.66GPa
alpha=14.4e-6; %Expansion coef, Alpha=10e-6 mm-1K-1
v=0.3; %Poisson modulus
a=101.6/1000; %Tube inner radius 101.6 mm
b=304.8/1000; %Tube outer radius 304.8 mm

%Calculation of internal and external temperature profiles
r=[a:(b-a)/19:b]; %20 divisions in radial coordinate
Theta=[0:360/71:360]; %72 divisions in circunferential coordinates
Theta=Theta*pi/180; %Angle in radians
T=zeros([size(Theta,2),size(r,2)]); %Temperature array, rows angle variation, column radial variation
for i=1:size(r,2) %To create temperature distribution (See Logie et al. Eq. 53)
    for i2=1:size(Theta,2)
        T(i2,i)=((555.56*b)/(b^2-a^2))*((r(i)^2-a^2)/r(i))*cos(Theta(i2))+277.78*(1- 
        log(b/r(i))/log(b/a))+273.15;
    end
end
```

Y el código de Python que tengo hasta ahora:

```
    import math
    from math import pi,cos,sqrt,log
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    #Holms case properties
    E=120.66e9     ##Young modulus E=120.66GPa
    alpha=14.4e-6 ##Expansion coef, Alpha=10e-6 mm-1K-1
    v=0.3 ##Poisson modulus
    a=101.6/1000 ##Tube inner radius 101.6 mm
    b=304.8/1000 ##Tube outer radius 304.8 mm
    c=20
    w=(b-a)/c
    z=72
    ang=360/z

    ##Calculation of internal and external temperature profiles
    r=[] 
    Theta=[]
    index=0
    for i in range(c):
      r.append(index)
      r[index]=a+index*w
      index=index+1
    index=0
    for i in range(0,73):
    Theta.append(index)
    Theta[index]=i*ang
    Theta[index]=Theta[index]*pi/180
    
w=len(r)
h=len(Theta)
 ##Angle in radians
T=np.zeros((w, h))##Temperature array, rows angle variation, column radial variation
for i in range(1, w):
    ##To create temperature distribution ##(See Logie et al. Eq. 53)
    for i2 in range(1, h):
        T[i2],[i]=((555.56*b)/(b**2-a**2))*((r(i)**2-a**2)/r(i))*cos(Theta(i2))+277.78*(1- 
                   log(b/r(i))/log(b/a))+273.15
```

Las constantes son números. El vector `r` es un array que va desde `a` hasta `b` con 20 divisiones, y el vector `Theta` igual, de 0 a 360 con 73 divisiones.

Con eso, creo una matriz de ceros de tamaño: filas =componentes de r y columnas=componentes de theta. No obstante, luego a cada componente de la matriz le tengo que asignar el valor de la formula que aparece al recorrer la matriz con los dos bucles for. Pero no me deja hacerlo, me sale el siguiente error en la línea 45:'list' object is not callable
No sé que pasa y me está costando adaptar el texto de matlab a oython, debe ser por el uso de corchetes o parentesis
si alguien sabe porque me sale ese error
gracias

Comment: Nadie sabe cómo luce lo que quieres hacer, ni siquiera conoce tu script de matlab. Ahora bien, el error que te está dando es porque las listas en python no se indexan con paréntesis, se indexan con corchetes. Por ejemplo, no es `r(i)`, es `r[i]`. No es `Theta(i2)`, es `Theta[i2]`. Por otro lado no se por que esperas que la operación que planteas te retorne dos cosas `T[i2], [i]`. No veo cómo puede retornar dos cosas, yo quitaría ese `,[i]`.

Comment: T es una matriz 2D, de len(r) filas y len(Theta) columnas. Lo que intento es recorrer la matriz para que a la fila i2 columna i me de un valor para así rellenar la matriz pero me sale el error. Le adjunto el script de matlab en la pregunta

Comment: Entonces usa `T[i][i2]`, no pongas una coma. Por otro lado, la indexación en python es diferente que en matlab, en python empieza en 0 y en matlab por 1, por tanto tus `for` deben ser: `for i in range(w)` y `for i2 in range(h)`.

Comment: genial por lo del range gracias no me habia dado cuenta. No obstante a pesar de quitar la coma, en la linea 45 me sigue saliendo el mismo error

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varios errores:

- Las listas en python no se indexan con paréntesis, se indexan con corchetes. Por ejemplo, no es `r(i)`, es `r[i]`. No es `Theta(i2)`, es `Theta[i2]`.
- Para indexar un arreglo bidimensional no se incluye una coma como lo pones `T[i2],[i]`.
- Puedes optimizar la creación de `r` y de `Theta` con `np.arange`.
- En python a diferencia de matlab, los índices comienzan en 0, no en 1.

Tu código corregido y reducido quedaría:

```
from math import pi, cos, sqrt, log
import numpy as np

E = 120.66e9;
alpha = 14.4e-6;
v = 0.3;
a = 101.6 / 1000;
b = 304.8 / 1000;

##Calculation of internal and external temperature profiles
r = np.arange(a, b + (b - a) / 20, (b - a) / 19)
Theta = np.arange(0, 360 + 360 / 71, 360 / 71)
Theta = Theta * pi / 180

T = np.zeros([len(Theta), len(r)])

for i in range(len(Theta)):
    for j in range(len(r)):
        T[i][j] = ((555.56 * b) / (b ** 2 - a ** 2)) * ((r[j] ** 2 - a ** 2) / r[j]) * cos(Theta[i]) + 277.78 * (
                    1 - log(b / r[j]) / log(b / a)) + 273.15
```

Comment: Hola jaime muchas gracias de verdad. No quiero ser pesado pero en el codigo de matlab(está entero) justo despues de %stress calculation, en el doble bucle me sale este error: list assignment index out of range, a que se debe?

Comment: Nunca pusiste esa parte en tu código de pyhon. No está en tu pregunta. Te arreglé el código de python hasta donde lo tenías hecho. Eso era lo que preguntabas.

Comment: ya justo pero ahora me sale error mas adelante y no puedo pone el codigo en comentarios, que hago?

Comment: A ver, tu pregunta hasta donde la preguntaste está resuelta. Acepta la respuesta si te ayudó. Si quieres incluir la parte del código que no adjuntaste inicialmente en tu pregunta, haz una nueva pregunta. Tu código de python nunca llegó a donde dice `%stress`.

Comment: vale, muchas gracias por la ayuda me sirvió mucho